# How to define the height of a button in a relative layout?

Tags: android, button, height, android-relativelayout

I have a button on a relative layout that hugs the buttom of the parent, but since there is not much above the button, the height of it is massive and extends to the object above it.  What kind of code can I use to make sure the button stays at a normal height while still hugging the bottom of the parent?

Comment: You need to provide more details on the specifics of your layout.  Better yet, you need to go read through the developer documentation on layouts carefully.  There is detailed information there, and if you understand it you won't need to ask a question every 30 seconds in order to make small changes.

Comment: And you also have to post some code or/and a screenshot showing us what's wrong.

Comment: @Mayra: +1. Asking a lot of questions is fine, asking a bunch of questions about the exact same topic because someone told you something and you're too lazy to google is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the height to wrap content

Comment: it still displays a massive button that extends up to the textView above it.

Comment: Are you setting the hight of the button to wrap_content? Then something else is wrong, we need to see your code.